# How to make my sidebar line up with footer no matter how much content?

Tags: html, css, alignment, sidebar

So I posted a question similar to this a little while ago, but altough I got help fixing part of my problem, I realized that my sidebar still won't do as I please.

The problem is, as of now, that I have a sidebar that I want to line up with my footer, but it stops after the "widgets". In other words, I want the sidebar to follow the **main** content all the way down to the footer, even though the sidebar itself won't always have enough content.

I've tried several ways of doing this, but I haven't found a good solution as of yet, can anyone help me with this? :)

Here is a [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ygDrK) of the project.

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an old school hack to get to where you need.

Let's assume something like this:

```
<div id="container">    //  Give it overflow: hidden;
  <div id="maincontent">
     Your main content goes here  // Assumes this is always taller than sidebar
  </div>
  <div id="sidebar">
     This is your sidebar stuff  // Give it a height of something like height: 16000 px;
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
   This is your footer stuff
</div>
```

Using this method, the sidebar will always be the tallest of everything, but since the container it is in has the overflow: hidden  in the CSS, the sidebar will only be as tall as your "maincontent" DIV

Part 2:

OK, I found the problem to my hack, I had forgotten an essential part:

Forget the sidebar: height: 16000px;

You need padding-bottom: 5000px   and margin-bottom: -5000px; // or whatever value you want, just remember margin-bottom has to be the same size as padding-bottom except a negative number

Comment: Don't forget, both maincontent and sidebar are float: left;

Comment: It seems when I do this the footer get's pushed down as well, leaving a huge gap in the content area...

Comment: Is the footer inside the "container" ? or outside the container?

Comment: The footer is outside the container. </div><!-- END #main-wrapper -->
<footer id="main-footer">

Comment: Finally, thaaaaank you kind sir! :D Amazing, simply amazing! I'm forever grateful!

Answer (score 0):

you should give both a class that is common, and use a script such as Equal Heights. See more here http://filamentgroup.com/lab/setting_equal_heights_with_jquery/ .

**Edit:** As an example, assuming you have included the library, and that both your elements ( sidebar and content container ) have the class `eq-height`, you need to add this block in your template `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('eq-height').equalHeights();
  });
<script>
```

Comment: Thank you :) This looks like just the thing I was looking for. I'm not familar with Javascript though, all I know is how to include it, do you mind explaining a bit? Like, is "(this)" the class name that I should change in the script?... And will this still work when I convert to a Wordpresstheme? Michael

Comment: added example to the above solution